# nullege alternatives for node examples

Tags: javascript, python

Are there any alternatives to [nullege](http://nullege.com) (which is for Python) for **your_favorite_programming_language** ? I am mainly interested in JavaScript examples to make my code more idiomatic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [Koders](http://www.koders.com)
2. [GitHub](https://github.com/search) may also be very useful (I am not sure if Koders searches in it)
3. Also searching on google may provide you with good results